# How to do replace segue between container viewers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, master-detail

I am trying to mimic `UISplitViewController` with container.

I have two contains, the left one (MasterView) and the right one (DetailedView). Inside each container, it is `UIViewController`.

The left one has a tableview inside it. The right one has a `UICollectionView` inside it.

I want to use left side tableviewcell segue to the right side collectionview (replace segue), so I click different tableviewcell, the content of the collectionview will change. But it does not work. The error message is as below.

> Could not find a split view controller ancestor for MasterViewController

I googled around, it seems the "replace segue" only works for splitview, is it correct?

But both my MasterViewController and Detailedview controllers are UIViewController.

How can I use "replace segue" from a tableviewcell inside Masterview to the collectionview inside the Detailed view?

Thanks.

Comment: I used delegate to accomplish the task.